# Guid[]:How to query and fetch details from Cosmos DB?

Tags: c#, .net, azure-cosmosdb

I am working with Azure CosmosDB. I am having below GetProgramsByStudentIDAsync method which needs to fetch all the programs associated to the studentID (**Note that studentID is of type Guid**).

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos;
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

     public async Task<ProgramContainer> GetProgramsByStudentIDAsync(Guid[] studentIds)
                {  
    
    var db = Client.GetDatabase(databaseId);
    
    var programContainer = db.GetContainer(containerId);     
                  
                using FeedIterator<ProgramContainer> feedIterator = programContainer.GetItemLinqQueryable<ProgramContainer>()
                    .Where(x => studentIds.Contains(x.StudentId)).ToFeedIterator(); //Giving me error at studentIds.Contains  Please find the error details below:
```

**CS1929: Guid[] does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload requires a receiver of type**

ProgramContainer class for reference:

```
public class ProgramContainer
    {
    public string ProgramName{ get; set; }
    public string ProgramCode { get; set; }
    public Guid StudentId { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    }
```

Please assist.Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Please show us the `using` statements at the top of the file.

Comment: `CS1929: Guid[] does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload requires a receiver of type` What is the **exact** error message?

Comment: @mjwills CS1929: Guid[] does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'MemoryExtensions.Contains<Guid>(ReadOnlySpan<Guid>,Guid)' requires a receiver of type 'ReadOnlySpan<Guid>'

Comment: Put `using System.Linq;` at the top of your file.

Comment: @mjwills I have added the top of the file in the question and the compiler error message below: **CS1929: Guid[] does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'MemoryExtensions.Contains<Guid>(ReadOnlySpan<Guid>,Guid)' requires a receiver of type 'ReadOnlySpan<Guid>'**

Comment: Does `Enumerable.Contains(studentIds, x.StudentId)` work instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try explicitly casting to guid

```
using FeedIterator<ProgramContainer> feedIterator = 
programContainer.GetItemLinqQueryable<ProgramContainer>()
                .Where(x => studentIds.Contains((Guid)x.StudentId)).ToFeedIterator();
```

Comment: I am quite surprised if this fixes the issue.

Comment: Reminder to everyone that Linq works properly only on Cosmos SDK4, not SDK 3.